# ServiceStack RedisMqHost with partitioned message queues

Tags: redis, servicestack

I'm implementing a solution whereby a number of nodes listen on a number of Redis message queues implemented using ServiceStack.Redis. Within the system each node services a specific "channel" and a particular operation on the channel. e.g. the message might be inbound email, and channel might be "abc".

There will be many channels but a fixed number of message types.

I've spent the weekend looking around within the ServiceStack source code and implemented a couple of variations on the RedisMessageQueueClient and RedisMqHost. The idea being that at construction you pass in the "channel" and this is then used in constructing the queue name that is to be published/mointored.

Internally the existing RedisMqHost and RedisMessageQueueClient use the QueueNames static to generate the queue names but because this generates a queue based purely on the type name I've no way of servicing just a specific channel. My updated code appends the channel name to the end of the queue name.

e.g. so for the "abc" channel the mq:InboundEmail:in would become mq:InboundEmail:in:abc

The code doesn't feel right in that I've changed just a couple of places but the QueueNames class is used throughout.

Two questions:

1. is the underlying design of having multiple message queues correct? Should this be modelled as multiple Redis databases (doesn't sound right) or is my design of having a large number of queues appropriate? I imagine we'd be looking at about a thousand channels and four or five queues per channel.
2. is there an existing mechanism for partitioning message queues that I've missed - it feels like a it should be a fairly standard requirement and it sort of happens underneath already in that there's the In queue, the Out queue and the Priority and Dlq queues per message type.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but couldn't you just implement different message types and register them accordingly?